# REST request does not bring any results using HTTPWebResponse

Tags: vb.net, rest

I'm trying to obtain some REST data using the following code:

```
Dim origResponse As HttpWebResponse
Dim objReader As StreamReader
Dim origRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://apoio.cfdevelopers.net/restAPI/broker.cfc?method=getOrders&token=12656773-44B0-4B52-93643CE7FBA69930&lastOrder=0"), HttpWebRequest)
origRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False
origRequest.Method = "GET"
origRequest.ContentType = "text/plain"
origResponse = DirectCast(origRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim Stream As Stream = origResponse.GetResponseStream()
Dim sr As New StreamReader(Stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
Dim str As String = sr.ReadToEnd()
```

This does not cause any exceptions, but at then end, "str" does not bring anything.
However, if I use the following code:

```
Dim sURL As String
Dim S As String
Dim xmlhttp As XMLHTTP
xmlhttp = New XMLHTTP
sURL = "http://apoio.cfdevelopers.net/restAPI/broker.cfc?method=getOrders&token=12656773-44B0-4B52-93643CE7FBA69930&lastOrder=1"
xmlhttp.open("GET", sURL, False)
xmlhttp.send()
MsgBox(xmlhttp.responseText)
```

In the same application and on the same machine, etc. I do get the result I need, but
I don't want to use the reference to MSXML2 in the programa (used it in vb5), so I wonder if anyone has a suggestion as to what to do.
Since using the first code example consuming other REST services works normally, I think this specific site needs some settings that I have not figured out.
If anyone wants to use the URL for testing, it's ok because it's a testing environment with no sensitive information. The result should be a JSON string with some orders placed on the site.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Try adding: `origRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate;q=0.8") origRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl, "no-cache")
origRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip Or DecompressionMethods.Deflate`. Otherwise you will probably receive a compressed stream that your `StreamReader` cannot handle. Note that all those objects, WebResponse and all the Streams, need to be disposed of. Also, you shouldn't decide on your own what is the encoding, hard-coding it: the WebResponse has that information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked fine!